# jQuery - Simple validation for two inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two inputs: the first one is X - file upload. the second one is Y- an input for an URL.

So far I have a code that checks if Y is valid then remove the attribute required for X. otherwise I want the X to be required.

```
$(Y).blur(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':valid') == true) {
        $(X).removeAttr('required')
    } else if ($(this).is(':valid') == false) {
        $(X).attr('required');
    }
});
```

for some reason this code works when the input Y is valid it removes the attribute. But let's say the user regrets and wants to leave Y blank, it doesn't return the required attribute for X.

Tried to keep the explanation as simple and clear as possible. If there is a misunderstanding I'll try to edit this question and make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
$(Y).blur(function(){
if ($(this).is(':valid') == true &&  $(this).val() != '') {
    $(X).removeAttr('required')
} else if ($(this).is(':valid') == false || $(this).val() == '') {
    $(X).attr('required');
}
```

});

In that case when user removes the content, required attribute will be returned back (dont forget to add trim function, I didnt use it in the sample).

I would recommend to capsulate this logic into validation functions. I also dont like blur event (usability is bad), I would recommend onchange event for field validation.